# Word scrambling app Android

Tags: android

I'm  developing a word scramble android app.. So basically I have a string array of words. I need to display the strings without repetition. This is what I've tried so far:

```
// shuffle algorithm
private String shuffleWord(String word){

    List<String>  letters = Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
    Collections.shuffle(letters);
    String Shuffled="";
    for (String letter : letters ){
        Shuffled += letter;
    }
    return Shuffled;
}

private void  newGame(){
    // get random word from dictionary
    currentWord= dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];

    // show the shuffled word
    tv_word.setText(shuffleWord(currentWord));

    // clear the textfield
    et_guess.setText("");

    // switch buttons
    b_new.setEnabled(false);
    b_check.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: than what is exact problem

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My Actual problem and my question is when i am using my code the words are repeating again and again.i want to display string of words by only once.if i found a correct word that word should not repeat again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different seed to get different pseudorandom number each time which can be used to randomize your word. Something like this:

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
currentWord= dictionary[random.nextInt(dictionary.length)];
```

Please read https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)